# What does "einen Zacken aus der Krone brechen" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

I came across this sentence:

> Das könnte manchem Sternsinger **einen Zacken aus der Krone brechen**: Von Königen steht in der Bibel nämlich nichts. Das Matthäus-Evangelium nennt die Männer, die dem Stern in Richtung Bethlehem folgen, „Magier“ aus dem Osten, nach dem griechischen Wort "magoi".

[Source](https://www.ndr.de/geschichte/Heilige-Drei-Koenige-Wer-waren-die-Weisen-aus-dem-Morgenland,dreikoenige112.html)

What does it mean? It seems to me that it is something along the lines of "it would break their heart" or maybe "they would never believe it", but I am not entirely sure. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

"Sich einen Zacken aus der Krone brechen" is a very tongue in cheek way to say you consider somebody to be overly proud, pretentious, big headed, full of themselves - or, alternatively, simply freaking lazy.

The image refers, as Si Langbein already mentioned, to an actual crown. It's like a mocking "Oh, of course, we can't expect your majesty to help with the housework. You would run the risk of accidently breaking off a tip of your crown, or getting a smudge on your royal cloak!"

The phrase is mostly used negated as a request for the person to get over themselves and do something they don't want to do:

> Du brichst dir keinen Zacken aus der Krone, wenn du auch mal den Müll rausbringst!
> You won't hurt your status if you take out the garbage, too, every once in a while!

or

> It's really not beneath you to take out the garbage, too, every once in a while!

The usage you quoted isn't typical, but more a play on words with the described phrase and the concept of [Sternsinger](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternsinger), who often actually wear crowns with their costumes. So,

> Das könnte manchem Sternsinger einen Zacken aus der Krone brechen: Von Königen steht in der Bibel nämlich nichts.

means something along the lines of

> This could cause some Sternsinger to get butthurt: The bible doesn't mention a word about kings.

Comment: [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=jemand%20bricht%20sich%20keinen%20Zacken%20aus%20der%20Krone&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp1=rart_varianten_ou&von=erg) lists the positive and negative versions. Similar is *Es könnte ja nicht schaden, wenn du mal ...* -- "It couldn't hurt if you...". "It couldn't hurt" works in American English; I'm not sure about other varieties.

Comment: @RDBury thanks for the interesting website link. However I don't find it supporting the non-negated use of "Zacken aus der Krone brechen", thus all examples I see are some variation of "kein Zacken aus der Krone brechen". (and from my personal experience, memory and usuage, I don't recall nor can I come up with a positive formulation either)

Comment: @planetmaker: Yes, I misread it somehow; the only entry is for the negative version. The positive version is still mentioned though.

Answer (score 0):

imagine an Eastern Crown, a gold heraldic crown surmounted with a variable number of sharp spikes. If one of these spikes falls off, you as king feel diminished. So it is more like a feeling of insult, then of "break their heart" or "would never believe it".
So, Sternsinger might feel like a king while in reality bible says it were magicians.

[see crown with spikes, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_crown)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. While I see benefit in referring to a crown where a single missing spike can "destroy" the entire image - I miss a little bit elaboration on the context (e.g. what Sternsinger might have believed until today what they represent vs. what they represent according to bible)